# QSlider setvalue() not updating slider position in GUI

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have multiple slider widget in my main window, added using QT creater, I am trying to set the slider position in my program, the slider value is set based on color (HSV) picked from a color picker dialog.

I have a color button, upon clicking color button,it invokes the color picker dialogue, after picking the color it calls `updateSlider()` to set slider position.

```
void MainWindow::on_Color_clicked()
{
    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::white);
    int h,s,v;
    color.getHsv(&h,&s,&v);
    h = h/2;
    ccfg.mHueL     = h;
    ccfg.mHueH     = h;
    ccfg.mSatL     = s;
    ccfg.mSatH     = s;
    ccfg.mValueL   = v;
    ccfg.mValueH   = v;
    updateSlider();
}

void MainWindow::updateSlider()
{
    ui->hueL->setValue(ccfg.mHueL);
    ui->hueH->setValue(ccfg.mHueH);
    ui->satL->setValue(ccfg.mSatL);
    ui->satH->setValue(ccfg.mSatH);
    ui->valL->setValue(ccfg.mValueL);
    ui->valH->setValue(ccfg.mValueH);
    ui->thrED->setValue(ccfg.mThrEd);
    ui->thrCD->setValue(ccfg.mThrCd);
    ui->minR->setValue(ccfg.mMinR);
}
```

After selecting the color only first sliders is getting updated, why the other sliders positions are not updated?

If I select the same color again the second slider position in UI gets updated to new value and if I select 9 times all sliders position gets set appropriately .

I tried calling `repaint()` of main window and widget, and also tried calling `processEvents()` nothing worked. Is there any way to force UI to update slider widget after `setValue()`?

Comment: The code looks ok, usually you do not need `repaint` or `processEvents` for this. Can you provide a verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I agree, this code should work, no repaint() or event processing is necessary, assuming the event loop is running normally (e.g. you called QApplication::exec())

Comment: I wont be able to post entire code here, I will try to reproduce the issue by moving problematic code to a new project.I am new to QT I thought I was missing something.

Comment: It seems it is a thread safe issue ( there is another thread which just read this object which I thought not an issue ), if I assign ccfg to a temporary object and  if I use temporary objects member  to set slider value, it works. Interestingly if I log values to debug, the members values are the same as  the dialog returned always.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not updating ccfg.mxxx values in the valueChanged slot function.